# Hicksian Demand Function

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, economics

Derive Hicksian demand for -

$$u(x,y) = ax+ b\ln(y)$$

Explain in words what they mean?

I solved the problem with the Lagrange Multiplier Method and found Hicksian demand for $x$ only.

Solution:
Suppose, the expenditure function is -

E = P1x + P2y

Subject to utility function -

u = ax + b ln y

Using Lagrange Multiplier for constrained optimization we get -

L = P_1 x+P_2 y+µ(u-ax-blny)

using first order condition for optimization -
∂L/∂x=P_1-aλ=0 …… (1)
∂L/∂y=P_2-bλ/y=0 ……. (2)
∂L/∂λ=u-ax-blny=0 ……. (3)
Now, dividing equation (1) by equation (2) –
y=P_1/P_2   .b/a 
Putting this value in equation (3), we get -

$$x = \frac1a \cdot \left[u - b\ln\left(\frac{P_1b}{P_2a}\right)\right] $$

I do not know how to explain this situation or demand function. Also, I do not understand how to find Hicksian demand for y from this. Is there any alternative method I should have used?

Comment: What was the constraint when you apply the Lagrange Multiplier method? Give a reply and add relevant information.

Comment: Can you show how the Lagrange function looks like?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: The definition is more or less: The Hicksian demand for good $x$ is the demand which depends on the prices of the goods and a minimum fixed utility. But I cannot obtain a Hicksian demand for y as well. It seems that the demand for y is independently from the utility: $y^*(P_1,P_2)=\frac{P_1b}{P_2a}$